# Ubuntu upgrade to 12.04: system crashed

Tags: 11.10, 12.04

During upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 the computer crashed. Now I cannot start the computer in a normal way anymore. I get a 'Unix-like screen' where I can type commands, but I have no idea what to do. I have a CD-ROM with version 11.10 but that does not start either and I have no idea how to access the CD-drive.

Comment: What prompt is displayed on your command line (Unix-like screen). Can you try something like `tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog`?

Answer (score 1):

something wrong happened while upgrading? connection lost? powered off?

you may try this to re-upgrade, first checking /etc/apt/source.list, and ensure that all all "deb","deb-src" lines reference to "precise" (if not, replace "oneiric"[11.10 codename] to "precise"[12.04 codename] with the vi)

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

Then execute the following command,
`sudo apt-get update`;
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

At last, execute `sudo apt-get autoremove` this will clean up the packages you may no longer needed.

Hope this helps and good luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "Nothing" happened during upgrading. The computer just stopped the installation of the upgrade. It got stuck in the middle of the process and I had to reset the computer. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: make sure your internet connection is okay while executing those commands. if this doesn't work either, try to insert a live cd and reference to Misery's simple way of re-upgrading :D

Answer (score 0):

Other (most simple) way is to insert the CD with Ubuntu 12.04, and during installation choose option to upgrade. There is quite a big chance that it will repair Your installation.
Regards

Comment: Thanks for our reply. I inserted the CD, but it doesn't start. Is there a Linux command to 'manually' start the CD?

Comment: What do You mean it doesn't start? Does it even try to boot from CD at all and then suspends? Or it doesn't even consider booting from CD? Maybe You need to press button (usually F8 or F12) while booting to choose BOOT MENU. And then choose CD. :) (While booting there is a message - press SOME KEY to enter BOOT MENU)

Comment: The computer does not try to boot from the CD. There is indeed a message during startup to choose BOOT MENU with a function key (don't remember which one), but the computer does not respond to that.

Comment: It should repond. Try to turn on Your PC and press all the time this key. If that wont help You need to enter the BIOS and change the boot order so, that first it will boot from CD and after from HD. In case of problems please see Your mainboards manual - there should be short description where to find those options and how to change them.

Comment: Press F12 (or possible key) 5 times per second immediately the bios information displays, this should navigate you to the boot menu :P

Answer (score 0):

From what you say you might have all the necessary packages downloaded and to hand, just their proper installation has failed.

Let's try the non-destructive bit first.

Immediately after the BIOS post hit the shift key. You should receive a grub prompt, listing the boot options. Select the one containing the term recovery Mode.

Hopefully after some text has scrolled by you will see a panel. Select the one dpkg (fix broken packages). Once the system has gone through the process (if you have a number of broken installs this might take some time. Then select resume normal boot.

You might just be lucky.

Comment: Hello all, thanks again for your support. Pressing the function key repeatedly to go to the boot menu worked. But then I only had the option to reinstall 11.10 from the CD again. So I did not succeed to upgrade to 12.04. I will now stick to the old version for the time being.